# I have an array containing n no of mail id. I want to sort it according to its domain name

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing n no of mail id. I want to sort it according to its domain name. i m not able to sort it when i run it gives domain name of all the id's that is it takes only else part.

---

```
<script>
    // var email ="test@gmail.com"
    //  var domain = email.replace(/.*@/," ");
    //  alert(domain);

    var d1 = "gmail.com"
    var d2 = "hotmail.com"
    var d3 = "yahoo.com"
    var email =[" test@gmail.com", "test@hotmail.com" , "test@yahoo.com"];
    var i;
    // var domain = email.replace(/.*@/," ");
    var text = "";
    for(i=0;i<email.length;i++){
        var dom = email[i].replace(/.*@/," ");
        if(dom[i]==d1){
          // text += email[i] + "<br>";

          // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
          document.write("hii hello");
        }
        else if(dom[i] == "hotmail.com"){
          // text += email[i] + "<br>";

          // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
          document.write("hii");
        }
        else if(dom[i] == "yahoo.com"){
          // text += email[i] + "<br>";

          // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
          document.write("swax");
        }
        else{
            document.write(dom);        }
    }
    // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you post and explain your expected output?

Comment: What is going on here? The provided code doesn't make sense at all ...

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method of `array`:

```js
let x = ["test@hotmail.com", "test@yahoo.com", "test@gmail.com"];

console.log('Before:');
console.log(x);

x.sort(function(a, b) {
  let domA = a.split('@')[1],
      domB = b.split('@')[1];  
  if (domA > domB) {
    return 1;
  } else if (domA < domB) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});

console.log('After:');
console.log(x);
```

---

**EDIT:**

This is how you can separate emails with different domains:

```js
let emails = [
    "a@hotmail.com", 
    "b@yahoo.com", 
    "c@gmail.com",
    "d@hotmail.com",
    "e@yahoo.com", 
    "f@gmail.com",
    "g@hotmail.com", 
    "h@yahoo.com", 
    "i@gmail.com",
  ],
  filteredEmails = {};

emails.forEach((el) => {
  let domain = el.split('@')[1];
  if (filteredEmails.hasOwnProperty(domain)) {
     filteredEmails[domain].push(el);
  } else {
    filteredEmails[domain] = [el];
  }
});

console.log(filteredEmails['gmail.com']);
console.log(filteredEmails['hotmail.com']); 
console.log(filteredEmails['yahoo.com']);
```

Comment: I want to segregate the mail ids based on domain like gmail must be inserted in gmail block and hotmail in hotmail block. not sorting please give me a quick response

Answer (score 0):

You could user `Array.prototype.sort` function to sort.

```js
var email =["test@zmail","test@gmail.com", "test@hotmail.com" , "test@yahoo.com"];
  
var sorted_emails = email.sort((a,b) => a.split("@")[1].localeCompare(b.split("@")[1]));

console.log(sorted_emails)
```